# Is a double times an unsigned unsigned long always a double?

Tags: objective-c, c, clang

```
unsigned long long i = 1000;
```

Shouldn't now `0.1*i` be automatically converted into a double? Why then isn't the compiler warning me when I pass `0.1*i` into a function parameter that expects an `unsigned long long`? I thought the compiler was supposed to warn of such potential loss of precision.

I have my compiler, Clang, configured with "-Weverything" to show me all possible warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, operation on an integer and a floating-point number results in a floating-point number. But when you pass that result (which is a double) to a function expecting an unsigned long long, then there'll be an implicit cast taking place automatically and the result will be truncated to unsigned long long.

Why didn't you get a warning? Because just like GCC, Clang's -Wall doesn't turn on all warnings - you can always use -Wextra to get really all the warnings.

Comment: Ah, ok. Turning on the "Suspicious Implicit Conversions" warning flag turned on the warning. I wonder why the hell "-Weverything" isn't what it claims to be. This is the second time this happens to me. It doesn't cover all warnings :(

Answer (score 4):

Because you can assign a value of any arithmetic type to an object of any arithmetic type and the standard does not require a warning for that.

```
unsigned long long a = 0.1;  // C does not require a warning
```

In the example above, `0.1` is converted to `unsigned long long` before the assignment.

And when passing an argument to a function in its prototype form, the argument is converted to the parameter type as if by assignment.